# Form Target _blank submits on both new page and current page

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, laravel

I'm setting up a form with a "Submit" button and a "Preview" button.

Everything is working fine with the submit button. However, the Preview button does indeed open up a new page with the preview but it also submits to the same preview on the actual form page, which is not what I intend, since the user loses all working data.

The JQuery code to allow for this is the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$( ":button" ).click(function(){
    var url = $(this).attr('data-url');
    if(url=="{{ URL::to('customdownloadpage/preview') }}") {
        $('#formCustom').target = "_blank";
    }
    $('#formCustom').attr('action',url);   
    $('#formCustom').submit();
});
});
</script>
```

The HTML for the buttons is the following:

```
<button data-url="{{ URL::to('customdownloadpage/new') }}" class="btn btn-primary">I'm Finished</button>
<button data-url="{{ URL::to('customdownloadpage/draft') }}" class="btn btn-primary">Save Draft</button>
<button style="float:right" data-url="{{ URL::to('customdownloadpage/preview') }}" class="btn btn-default">Preview</button>
```

Why is the form submitting twice (on a _blank page and on the self)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try preventing the default submission:

```
$( ":button" ).click(function(e){
    var url = $(this).attr('data-url');
    if(url=="{{ URL::to('customdownloadpage/preview') }}") {
        $('#formCustom').target = "_blank";
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    $('#formCustom').attr('action',url);   
    $('#formCustom').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the preview button an anchor tag instead of a button. Buttons always seem to serve as submit triggers inside forms, so if you use a tags with the btn class you get the looks of a button without all the events.